# Angular2 frontend Spring Boot backend on Google cloud platform

Tags: java, spring, angular, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have an Angular2 front-end and a Java Spring Boot back-end with my REST endpoints.

Now I want to deploy this app to Google cloud platform, but I want to keep my projects separate.

All I've read is about deploying one single application, but I want to keep my front-end and back-end separate.

How can I deploy my separate projects to Google cloud platform and have them communicate here as well?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I guess you need some server which serves your HTML+JS files? It's quite common to take advantage of Spring Boot's provided Tomcat for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this in GCP would be to host the frontend in Cloud Storage and set up your backend in Google Compute Engine (GCE) or App Engine.

#### Frontend

Cloud Storage provides static hosting capabilities. You can upload your frontend files to a Cloud Storage bucket and configure your domain to serve content from that bucket. [Here is a tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website) for setting a bucket up for static hosting.

Once your backend REST endpoints are set up, the frontend app can easily communicate with them using Angular's AJAX capabilities.

#### Backend

If you prefer direct access to the machine your server runs on, you can upload the backend code to a GCE instance and run the server there. Otherwise, I would recommend deploying the server using App Engine, which will manage the instances for you.

One point you might be interested in is configuring permssions for your backend endpoints. If you want to restrict access to those endpoints and only allow your frontend to communicate with them, try out the [Google VPC](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpc/) firewall features.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Have you tried this? I checked the reference tutorial. Didn't understood how to deploy angular using it. Would you please share your steps?

Comment: I able to deploy it to google app engine. Now I got stuck how to redirect api calls to rest endpoints which are deployed as another service.

Comment: Able to resolve issue [Thanks to this blog](https://jaykhimani.blogspot.com/2016/10/deploying-angular-2-app-with-angular.html)